# Display TextLabel Text Over Custom Cell Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to display cell's textLabel text to be visible on top of an image that spans the entire cell.  I created a custom cell subclass just to make the image width be equal to the entire cell size like so:

```
 - (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,80);
}
```

Now I would like to display my cells text on top of the cell.  I do not have the cell text in the custom cell subclass, rather the code for it is in the TableViewController.  Is there a way I can make the text display on top from within the view controller or do I have to put the text to be displayed in the custom cell subclass? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to make a custom cell, with an imageView and a label, and add them to the subview when the cell is initialized.

Then make sure they're hooked up to a property so you can configure the frame, as well as the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the text in the TableViewController. Just make sure you set the image first before you set the text. I have provided code snippet in the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 cell.imageView.image = theImage;
 UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0,100.0, 30.0)];
 textLabel.text = @"Testing";
 [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
```